# How to pass content of file as a pipeline parameter

Tags: azure, parameter-passing, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline that accepts an array as parameters.
Currently, an array has been hardcoded as the default value.

Is it possible to make this dynamic? there is a file called Array.txt in azure blob which is updated frequently, how can I extract the content of Array.txt and pass it as parameter values to the Pipeline.

I tried using Lookup but receive error 'Object cannot be passed, pipeline is expecting an Array'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure the data in Array.txt is array format-compatible, then use a lookup activity for data extracting, pass **@array(activity('Lookup1').output.value)** to the subsequent activity. Remember to use **@array()** function to convert data into an Array.